# How to prevent the plugin for nested schemas

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

I have a mongoose schema for categories

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { imageScheme } from './data.schemas';

mongoose.plugin(require('mongoose-delete'));
mongoose.plugin(require('mongoose-timestamp'));
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const catScheme = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String
    },
    subTitle: {
        type: String
    },
    description: {
        type: String
    },
    images: [imageScheme],
    icon: {
        type: String
    },
    deleteAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: null
    }
});

const Category = mongoose.model('Category',catScheme);

export default Category;
```

my image schema is located in another file

```
const imageScheme = new Schema({
    imageCaption : {
        type: String
    },
    imageFileName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    imagePath: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    } 
});
```

and when I am using the model for creating new category its adding the timestamp and deleted for my images array which means its loading the plugins ( mongoose-delete , mongoose-timestamp ) into the sub schema

HOW TO AVOID THAT ?

that is the result

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d5a822f20179023e008f10c"),
    "deleteAt" : null,
    "deleted" : false,
    "title" : "Eyes and Ears",
    "description" : "here you will find all ppe to keep your eye 6 sharp",
    "icon" : "glass.svg",
    "images" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d5a822f20179023e008f10e"),
            "deleted" : false,
            "imageCaption" : "Eyes and Ears",
            "imageFileName" : "67acca17-3fc8-416c-bc00-8273770b2115.jpeg",
            "imagePath" : "resources/images/67acca17-3fc8-416c-bc00-8273770b2115.jpeg",
            "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-08-19T11:04:15.756Z"),
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-08-19T11:04:15.756Z")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d5a822f20179023e008f10d"),
            "deleted" : false,
            "imageCaption" : "Eyes and Ears",
            "imageFileName" : "9f1c5b1f-c1be-48f2-a9bc-8294930fd4c9.jpeg",
            "imagePath" : "resources/images/9f1c5b1f-c1be-48f2-a9bc-8294930fd4c9.jpeg",
            "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-08-19T11:04:15.756Z"),
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-08-19T11:04:15.756Z")
        }
    ],
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-08-19T11:04:15.756Z"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-08-19T11:04:15.756Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are plugging the `mongoose-delete` and `mongoose-timestamp` in the whole database.

Have you tried the example provided in the plugin pages?

`catScheme.plugin(mongoose-timestamp)`

`catScheme.plugin(mongoose-delete)`